# How to add modular extension wiredesignz to codeigniter 3.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-hmvc

I'm trying to add third party extension to create a HMVC application using Codeigniter 3.0

But when I'm adding `MY_Loader` and `MY_Router` files into the core folder and MX folder in the `Third_party` folder, it generates a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method MY_Loader::_ci_object_to_array()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\third_party\MX\Loader.php
>   on line 300.

When I remove them, the application works perfectly. Are there any additional settings that are needed to get the application running?

Comment: https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/ec8dbbb79bb083acd1cf6beff5abea055b583db5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It happens because the function used in MX/Loader.php no longer exists in CodeIgniter.

You can add it back to `Loader.php`

```
protected function _ci_object_to_array($object) {
    return is_object($object) ? get_object_vars($object) : $object;
}
```

[Source](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/pull-requests/17/fix-loaderphp-for-ci-313/diff#comment-None)

Answer (score 3):

Open your file application/third_party/MX/Loader.php

```
protected function _ci_object_to_array($object) {
    return is_object($object) ? get_object_vars($object) : $object;
}
```

add above function in Loader class.

Answer (score 1):

*On Line 300 of application/third_party/MX/Loader.php*

This line generates an error with CI 3.1.3

```
 return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
```

Replace with this line.

```
return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following solution

In application/third_party/MX/Loader.php you can change the following.

Under public function view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE) Look for... (near about Line 300)

```
return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
```

Replace this with

```
if (method_exists($this, '_ci_object_to_array'))
{
        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
} else {
        return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
}
```

Maybe wiredesignz will soon release the update for it. In the meantime, you can implement the above fix and resume coding.

Answer (score 0):

I replace on /MX/Loader.php line 300

```
return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
```

with

```
return (method_exists($this, '_ci_object_to_array') ? $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return)) : $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return)));
```